# How to open/close a modal in Salesforce Lightning App?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I saw this document about [modals](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/modals/?variant=base#react-target).

But there is no guild-line for waking up a modal from button or anything like bootstrap.

Do you guys know how could I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Salesforce lightning we don't have any built in function to open/close Modals, This one is working for me.

Component

```
<div aura:id="exampleModal"  class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open hideDiv" aria-hidden="false" role="dialog">
        <div class="slds-modal__container" style="max-width:50rem;">
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--icon-inverse slds-modal__close" onclick="{!c.hideExampleModal}">
                    <lightning:icon iconName="utility:close" size="medium" variant="bare"/>
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Example Modal</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                <div class="modalContent">
                   <p>Content goes here</p> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.hideExampleModal}">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Controller.js

```
    hideExampleModal : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.hideExampleModal(component);
    },
    
    showExampleModal : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.showExampleModal(component);
    },
```

Helper.js

```
    showExampleModal : function(component) {      
        var modal = component.find("exampleModal");
        $A.util.removeClass(modal, 'hideDiv');        
    },
    
    hideExampleModal : function(component) {
        var modal = component.find("exampleModal");
        $A.util.addClass(modal, 'hideDiv');
    },
```

In Style

```
.THIS.hideDiv {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default Modal is open. You need to control using aura:if.

Comment: In some system functionalities (for e.g.: accounts), lightning opens a modal smoothly, it doesn't look like they use `aura:if`, but some standard functions.

Comment: As per my knowledge, we can open custom popups in two ways. 
One is using lightning quick action - It is a kind of button and a lightning component opens on click of this action.
Second is using slds-modals. We do not have any open/close modals. By default it is Open. To toggle this open/close, we generally use aura:if. or  some css ( as mentioned in below post )